# getting information out an api in php

Tags: php, json, curl

I want to make an currency converter in php with the use of the fixer.io api 
with the use of mysql
at the moment this is mine code

```
$ch = curl_init();
$url ='http://api.fixer.io/latest';
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);


$json= curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
$data = json_decode($json);

foreach ($data as $rate){

    $AUD = $rate->AUD;
    $BGN = $rate->BGN;
    $BRL = $rate->BRL;
    $CAD = $rate->CAD;
    $CHF = $rate->CHF;
    $CNY = $rate->CNY;
    $CZK = $rate->CZK;
    $DKK = $rate->DKK;
    $GBP = $rate->GBP;
}
```

the json looks like when i var_dump($data)

```
{
    "base": "EUR",
    "date": "2016-05-23",
    "rates": {
        "AUD": 1.5542,
        "BGN": 1.9558,
        "BRL": 3.9832,
        "CAD": 1.4745,
        "CHF": 1.1105,
        "CNY": 7.3507,
        "CZK": 27.033,
        "DKK": 7.4371,
        "GBP": 0.77443,
        "HKD": 8.7104,
        "HRK": 7.489,
        "HUF": 317.05,
        "IDR": 15232.77,
        "ILS": 4.3459,
        "INR": 75.7263,
        "JPY": 122.7,
        "KRW": 1329.78,
        "MXN": 20.6021,
        "MYR": 4.5816,
        "NOK": 9.3658,
        "NZD": 1.6538,
        "PHP": 52.481,
        "PLN": 4.4367,
        "RON": 4.521,
        "RUB": 75.2277,
        "SEK": 9.344,
        "SGD": 1.5478,
        "THB": 39.993,
        "TRY": 3.3495,
        "USD": 1.1215,
        "ZAR": 17.5173
    }
}
int(1))
```

I want to use the rates and put them in mysql.
mine question is how do you get the  rates allone 
when i use foreach i get

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in \index.php on line
>   12

another question i dont understand where the int(1) came from in the json (if I comment the foreach i shows like show here but if i uncomment the foreach it show beneath the warning

How do i solve this? Any help is welcome!

Comment: you are decoding this as a stdClass, and processing the decode result as an associative array. If you want an associative array, use `json_decode($json, true);`.

Comment: tried that changed the  $data = json_decode($json); to $data = json_decode($json, true); got the same massage

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a `foreach` loop, there's just a single `rates` element in the response. So it's just:

```
$rates = $data->rates;
$AUD = $rates->AUD;
$BGN = $rates->BGN;
...
```

Answer (score 0):

you are missing the hierarchy inside the json payload.

```
$data = json_decode($json);
foreach($data->rates as $key=>$value){     // get to the rates array
  $$key = $value;
}
```

This creates on the fly a var named $AUD for the key `AUD`, etc. However, i would chose another approach, you could have invalid keys in the payload, and fail silently.